# Defusing Bomb lab phase_6

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I am doing the bomb lab that I have to defuse the bomb by debugging the disassembled binary. But I have no idea how to debug this phase in order to get the answer. Help would be really appreciated. It will be great if someone can figure out the answer, but some insight would be great too.

Phase 6

```
0x08048e13 <+0>:    sub    $0x2c,%esp
0x08048e16 <+3>:    lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax
0x08048e1a <+7>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
0x08048e1e <+11>:   lea    0x18(%esp),%eax
0x08048e22 <+15>:   mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x08048e26 <+19>:   movl   $0x804a5b1,0x4(%esp)
0x08048e2e <+27>:   mov    0x30(%esp),%eax
0x08048e32 <+31>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048e35 <+34>:   call   0x8048870 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x08048e3a <+39>:   cmp    $0x2,%eax
0x08048e3d <+42>:   jne    0x8048e4b <phase_6+56>
0x08048e3f <+44>:   mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
0x08048e43 <+48>:   sub    $0x2,%eax
0x08048e46 <+51>:   cmp    $0x2,%eax
0x08048e49 <+54>:   jbe    0x8048e50 <phase_6+61>
0x08048e4b <+56>:   call   0x8049395 <explode_bomb>
0x08048e50 <+61>:   mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
0x08048e54 <+65>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x08048e58 <+69>:   movl   $0x7,(%esp)
0x08048e5f <+76>:   call   0x8048dc9 <func6>
0x08048e64 <+81>:   cmp    0x18(%esp),%eax
0x08048e68 <+85>:   je     0x8048e6f <phase_6+92>
0x08048e6a <+87>:   call   0x8049395 <explode_bomb>
0x08048e6f <+92>:   add    $0x2c,%esp
0x08048e72 <+95>:   ret
```

Function 6

```
0x08048dc9 <+0>:    push   %edi
0x08048dca <+1>:    push   %esi
0x08048dcb <+2>:    push   %ebx
0x08048dcc <+3>:    sub    $0x10,%esp
0x08048dcf <+6>:    mov    0x20(%esp),%ebx
0x08048dd3 <+10>:   mov    0x24(%esp),%esi
0x08048dd7 <+14>:   test   %ebx,%ebx
0x08048dd9 <+16>:   jle    0x8048e07 <func6+62>
0x08048ddb <+18>:   mov    %esi,%eax
0x08048ddd <+20>:   cmp    $0x1,%ebx
0x08048de0 <+23>:   je     0x8048e0c <func6+67>
0x08048de2 <+25>:   mov    %esi,0x4(%esp)
0x08048de6 <+29>:   lea    -0x1(%ebx),%eax
0x08048de9 <+32>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048dec <+35>:   call   0x8048dc9 <func6>
0x08048df1 <+40>:   lea    (%eax,%esi,1),%edi
0x08048df4 <+43>:   mov    %esi,0x4(%esp)
0x08048df8 <+47>:   sub    $0x2,%ebx
0x08048dfb <+50>:   mov    %ebx,(%esp)
0x08048dfe <+53>:   call   0x8048dc9 <func6>
0x08048e03 <+58>:   add    %edi,%eax
0x08048e05 <+60>:   jmp    0x8048e0c <func6+67>
0x08048e07 <+62>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x08048e0c <+67>:   add    $0x10,%esp
0x08048e0f <+70>:   pop    %ebx
0x08048e10 <+71>:   pop    %esi
0x08048e11 <+72>:   pop    %edi
0x08048e12 <+73>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Might help with insight and answer [Binary Bomb Lab :: Phase 6](http://zpalexander.com/binary-bomb-lab-phase-6/)

Comment: :))) do you keep deleting your posts after a few minutes or are they deleted by someone else?

Comment: The linked duplicate is a 64 bit version of this, but the logic is the same. Also don't mind the phase numbers :)

Comment: @Jester I still couldn't figure it out, anyone has the answer?